# Predicting multiple variables at once with Facebook Prophet

Tags: python, pandas, facebook-prophet

I'm new to both Python and Facebook Prophet, so this may be a no-brainer, but I haven't been able to find an answer online.

I have a 7-column csv file. One column contains a datestamp ('ds') column with daily increments, and the other 6 columns ('y1', 'y2', 'y3', etc.) contain 6 variables whose values align with the datestamps.

Instead of creating six different two-column csv files and running Prophet six different times (predicting only one variable at a time), I'd like to find a way to predict all six variables at once. Here's what I'm trying:

```
df = pd.read.csv('example_file.csv')
cols = ['y1','y2','y3','y4','y5','y6']
results = []
for col in cols:
    subdf = df[['ds', col]].dropna()
    m = Prophet()
    m.fit(subdf)
    result = m.predict(m.make.future.dataframe(periods = 90))
    results.append(result)
df.predict = pd.concat(results, axis=1)
df.predict.to_csv('example_file.csv')
```

When I run it, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Dataframe must have columns 'ds' and 'y' with the dates and values respectively.
```

Any insight/help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The error message is quite clear: the second column must be named 'y'. Are you trying to fix your code, or get a whole new approach?

Comment: I was basically looking for the answer that warwick12 gave me. I know that Prophet wants the second column to be named 'y', but I didn't know how to achieve that with multiple columns.

Comment: If you like the answer, go ahead and accept it. That will remove your question from the unanswered queue and get you and warwick some points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry I wanted to comment but I don't have sufficient reputation yet. Please rename your columns in the loop

```
subdf = subdf.rename(columns={'ds':'ds', col:'y'})
```

Prophet imposes the strict condition that the input columns be named ds (the time column) and y (the metric column).

Comment: Thanks so much! That did the trick! (I also needed to use underscores instead of periods for "make_future_dataframe".) Now I'm wondering how to export ONLY the yhat values for each variable (and not 'trend', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper', etc.).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer is perfectly fine as an answer. +1 and hopefully OP selects it.

Comment: @Chuck , Thank you for accepting the answer guys. You can just do this to get only 'yhat' column : result_df = result[['ds', 'yhat']] and then append this to results. This should do the trick.